# Is there is a way to paginate a list server side?

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code in my HTML page(MVC View), which receives a List of model and i want to make that list paginated .

`@model List<Model>`

`@foreach (var item in Model)`

`{`

> Some HTML Code

`}`

I want to know if there is a possible way to do that based on server side.

Note: my SP is built using pagination and all I want is a JQuery library that serves my needs.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of JQuery pagination plugins. Most of them will suit your needs just fine. There's also Bootstrap pagination. Either will serve just fine. Go have a look on the respective sample pages of both.

Comment: Couldn't you add a parameter 'page' to your request and use it with .Skip(page * PAGE_LENGTH).Take(PAGE_LENGTH) while creating your List?